# PHP: Exploding string by space includes spaces in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have string with several spaces, including double spaces and spaces at the start and end of the string:

```
 12 345  67 89
```

I want to add just the numbers into array so used:

```
explode(" ", $s);
```

But this adds spaces to to the array as well.

Is there a way to add only the numbers to the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `preg_split()` instead of `explode()`:

```
preg_split('/\s+/', $str);
```

This will split the string using one or more space as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take all spaces into consideration at once, why not use `preg_split()`like so:

```
<?php
    $str  = "12 345  67  89";
    $res  = preg_split("#\s+#", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

i have applied this code  , please have a look

```
<?php

$data = "12 345  67 89";

$data = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$data);
var_dump(explode(' ',$data));
die;

?>
```

i suppose most of the code is understandable to you , so i just explain this to you :
`preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$data)`

in this code , the preg_replace replaces one or more occurences of ' ' into just one ' '.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$numbers = " 12 345  67 89";

$numbers = explode(" ", trim($numbers));

$i = 0;

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    if ($number == "") {
        unset($numbers[$i]);
    }

    $i++;
}
var_dump(array_values($numbers));
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "12"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "345"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "67"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "89"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `trim` with `preg_split`

```
$str = " 12 345  67 89";

$data = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($str), $str);
```

`trim()` is used to remove space before the first and behind the last element. (which preg_split() doesn't do - it removes only spaces around the commas)